# Выдача ошибки TypeError

Tags: python

На 2 строчке когда пишу float, выдаёт ошибку

```
import math
x1, y1 = float(input().split())
x2, y2 = float(input().split())
result = math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)
print(float(round(result, 4)))
```

Comment: Лучше всегда добавляйте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (ссылка `править` под вопросом), так будет проще помогать с их решением :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

следует использовать map, чтобы применить float к каждому элементу списка, полученного с помощью split, потому что нельзя список конвертировать во float

```
import math
x1, y1 = map(float, input().split())
x2, y2 = map(float, input().split())
result = math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)
print(float(round(result, 4)))
```